is it possible to negatively charge a wire?
Lets say I charge a parallel plate capacitor.
I then remove that capacitor from the circuit, and then separate the plates, and connect a wire to the negative plate. Will this lead to an influx of charge into that wire and negatively charge it?
Are there any better ways of negatively charging a wire?

What would be the final application of the negatively charged wire?

I believe the answer is yes, charge can be moved around in such a way. That's what static electricity is.

Like charges repel, so electrons would disperse over full volume / surface.
